# Django on Ubuntu Linux: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, python, python3, django

Trying to install django on Linux Ubuntu (via virtual machine). Python3, pip3 successfully installed (because I can successfully verify the version of each on my machine).

```
   > sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.6.7-1~18.04).
python3-pip is already the newest version (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 332 not upgraded.
```

When I try to install django, this error message is displayed.

```
    > pip3 install Django
Collecting Django
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1fe92a5b70>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1fe92a5d30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1fe92a5cc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1fe92a5f60>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/django/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f1fe92a5e10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',)': /simple/django/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for Django
```

Kinda new to Linux troubleshooting; feedback appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the last line of the error message `No matching distribution found for Django` - it says that `pip3` cannot find a distribution named `Django`. That's because distribution names are case sensitive.

What you want is `pip3 install django`.

The `django` module is all lowercase.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! But see, the exact same error message appears even with django is lowercase.

Comment: @deevs_hari Can you install anything with `pip3` such as `numpy` or `matplotlib` or `virtualenv`?